# VB.NET SMO Restore code working on local SQL Server instance but not on other SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, smo

I am using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` namespace to restore a database bak file from my local SQL Server instance to another SQL Server instance in another pc.

My winform app can connect to that SQL Server instance (it can query that instance & drop database from it) but when I tried smo restore it encountering:

> FailedOperationException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Directory lookup for the file 'C\Program Files SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS01\DATA\ClientTest.MDF failed with the operation system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)

This path ('C\Program Files SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS01\DATA) is in my local pc. While the remote sql instance path is 'C\Program Files SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\DATA

Here is my restore code:

```
Public Sub SMORestore(bkUpFile As String, dbName As String)


        Dim conn As ServerConnection = New ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password)
        Dim srv As Server = New Server(conn)

        Dim res As Restore = New Restore()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

        Try
            res.Database = dbName
            res.Action = RestoreActionType.Database

            res.Devices.AddDevice(bkUpFile, DeviceType.File)


            res.Database = dbName
            res.NoRecovery = False
            res.ReplaceDatabase = True

            res.SqlRestore(srv)

            MessageBox.Show("Restore of " & dbName & " Complete!", "Restore", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

            conn.Disconnect()

        Catch exSMO As SmoException

            MessageBox.Show(exSMO.ToString())
        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        Finally
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.[Default]

        End Try
    End Sub
```

It working fine on my local SQL Server instance but not on another pc's SQL Server instance.

What going on with my code?

Comment: You can't restore between machines. The backup file has to be on the same machine as the instance.

Comment: Is that path even correct though? Surely you're missing at least one slash in that path.

Comment: This path I just type it so it missing a slash. 'C:\Program Files\SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS01\DATA\ClientTest.MDF

Comment: I can't restore between machines thru code? Is that what you mean because when I use SSMS I can restore the bak file to the other machine. It a requirement to do it on vb.net code.

Comment: When the bak file is from sql server that have lower version(2017) that the remote sql server(2019) my code work all the time. But if the bak file came from the same sql server version(2019) with the remote sql server(2019), my code sometimes work, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Using select @@version both on local instance and remote instance  yields the same build version: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5